# Set a values folder for multiple android sdk versions

Tags: android, styles

I would like to set a values folder for multiple sdk verions to set a theme for everything under sdk 19. I have tried doing:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            getApplication().setTheme(R.style.HomeTheme4);
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_launch_screen);
[.....]
}
```

But this doesnt seem to set the theme For the whole app.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could place your theme that you want to use for **API-19 and above** inside the folder:

```
/values-v19
```

and the default values folder then will handle everything **below API-19**:

```
/values
```

see related android [resource qualifiers documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).

Comment: For now this would work, but what would I do when android 5.0 and 5.1 and 5.2 etc are released ?

Comment: create a `/values-v20` then and put the layout to handle API 20 and above if that turns out necessary. If you don't create a -v20 folder then API-20, API-21 etc. would take the -v19 values

Comment: Sorry ya wouldnt let me accept the answer last night

Comment: Wow, this spared me a lot of headache trying to use AppCompat themes from v21 on an Android V16 build.Changing the folder from `values-v21` to `values-v16` worked!